# Ignore the initial value of the parameter in calculation

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

I have the following code. The formula is `answer = (b*a)+c`. I want to display `a` and the `answer`

```
c = 9
qq = 4
b = 5
a = 0


for i in range(5):
    answer = (b*a)+c
    a += qq

    print a, answer
```

Once this program runs, it displays its values starting from

```
4 9
```

up to

```
20 89
```

It runs fine, but I do not want 9 to be displayed beside 4. Instead I want 29 to be displayed beside 4 because that is the answer when 4 is plugged in for `a`. I've been trying for an hour now, but I do not know how to do that.

Comment: Why do you increment `a` after calculating `answer` but before displaying it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because your iterating a before you display it.

```
c = 9
qq = 4
b = 5
a = 0

for i in range(5):
    answer = (b*a)+c
    print a, answer
    a += qq
```

will display:

```
0 9
4 29
...
20 109
```